# how to create apollo client query with custom types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have to do a query and I have to pass a nested variable.
Below is the working query when I use apollo graphql client interface. It is giving me expected result. Below is the working query

```
query($input: MyProductInput!){
  MyProductCategories(input: $input){
    id,
    name
  }
}
```

Variable which i am passing

```
{
  "input": {
    "locale": "ENG"
  }
}
```

`MyProductInput` type look like this at SERVER

```
type MyProductInput {
  locale: Locale!
}
enum Locale {
  IND
  AUS
  ENG
}
```

when I try to call the same query from my React App, it is giving me error, It says 400 bad request. My React query look like this.

```
const PRODUCT_LIST = gql`
  query ($locale: String!) {
    MyProductCategories(input: {locale: $locale}){
      id,
      name
    }
  }
`;

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(PRODUCT_LIST, {
  variables: {
    "input": {
      "locale": "ENG"
    }
  },
});
```

How can i convert my react query to accommodate custom types??

***Note**: I am using JavaScipt not Typescript at Front-end side*

Comment: did you checked in graphiql?

Comment: Nisharg shah, yes I checked in graphiql and I have mentioned that also in the question that `its working fine in apollo graphql client interface`

Comment: please remove the comma between `id, name`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I just had to do this `$input: MyProductInput!` within query and pass `$input` to `MyProductCategories`. Below is working example.

```
const PRODUCT_LIST = gql`
  query ($input: MyProductInput!) {
    MyProductCategories(input: $input){
      id,
      name
    }
  }
`;
```

React Query using hooks

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(PRODUCT_LIST, {
  variables: {
    "input": {
      "locale": "ENG"
    }
  },
});
```

No need to worry about custom types as it is already there at server. Just pass is as it is and set the variables

Answer (score -1):

Take a look in the docs:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/

And can you see more information about the error message you get back?

Comment: That doesn't help. I have already gone through the apollo doc and related stack-overlow before posting it here.

Comment: Can you find some detail error message in the console? Or on the network tab off devtools?
Normally you can see the post or get request and some error message with details come back from the GraphQL server

Comment: GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED, Cannot query field "MyProductCategories" on type "Query". 
However same query is running on apollo client in chrome. 
Question here is how to pass custom types in query, that is 
`type MyProductInput {locale: Locale!}`